# Marmalade HTTP GET not receiving entire response

Tags: http, marmalade

Here is my code:

```
CIwHTTP http;
std::string output="";
char buffer[1024];

int32 httpCallback(void* sys_data, void* user_data) {
       http.ReadData(buffer,http.ContentLength());
       output += buffer;
    return 0;
}

http.Get(url.c_str(), httpCallback, 0);
```

The content-length header is properly set in the API. For some reason only part of the API output is received. Sometimes it gets the entire API string and sometimes it returns different portions of the string. It seems random. Help!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `ContentLength()` to `ReadData`, but your buffer has only 1024 bytes. Most likely you have stack overflow - pun intended.

You can either call ReadData in a loop with 1024 until it returns zero, or dynamically allocate `buffer` on the heap.

Comment: When I set buffer to the content length, just to see if it works, it still does't work. char buffer[6738];

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? What does the buffer contain? What is the return value of `ReadData`?

Comment: the return value of ReadData is only a portion of the contents of the API output, even with the char buffer set to the content length of the API output.

Comment: This is why you need to call this function in a loop. Also you need to maintain the latest buffer pointer and append to it on further callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

`IwHTTP::Get()` only performs the callback once the headers for the response have been received.

You then need to use `IwHTTP::ReadContent()` to actually read the remainder of the response in a series of callbacks, as hinted at in one of the other comments.

Please see the **[IwHTTP Example](http://api.madewithmarmalade.com/ExampleIwHTTP.html)** in our API reference documentation for more details.

Hope this helps!